# iBeacon App only working sometimes, transmitting never working on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I am having a really weird problem here. I am trying to build an app to detect beacons. I don't have any real beacons yet so I am testing with an iPhone 5 and an iPad 3. The strange thing is that the transmitting is only working on the iPad, the iPhone doesn't work as a transmitter even though I used the same app on it.

But even with the iPad as a transmitter, the app only works sometimes - sometimes the iPhone will notify me that it has found a beacon, sometimes it doesn't. I've force-closed the app on the iPad and after the restart it worked, but then another time it doesn't. 
Since everything is working sporadically I think it can't be the code causing that behaviour, but it might be - I am not an experienced coder, I've just started this. My code is based on this tutorial http://www.devfright.com/ibeacons-tutorial-ios-7-clbeaconregion-clbeacon/

I first thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21707853/2700042) might be the answer, but taht didn't solve it: it still did work sometimes, and sometimes it didn't.

Can anybody tell me what I am dealing with her?

Here is my code for the Tracker:

ladBeaconTracker.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@interface ladBeaconTracker : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *beaconFoundLabel;

@end
```

ladBeaconTracker.m

```
#import "ladBeaconTracker.h"

    @interface ladBeaconTracker ()

    @property NSUUID *uuid;

@end  

@implementation ladBeaconTracker

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    [self initRegion];
}  

- (void)initRegion {
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"A5456D78-C85B-44C6-9F20-8268FD25EF8A"];
    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc]initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"Museum"];

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];

    NSLog(@"Region %@ initated", _beaconRegion.identifier);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region { 
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];       
    self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;

    NSLog(@"Region %@ entered", _beaconRegion.identifier);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];

    NSLog(@"Region %@ exit", _beaconRegion.identifier);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{
    CLBeacon *beacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init];
    beacon= [beacons lastObject];    
    self.beaconFoundLabel.text =@"Yes";

    NSLog(@"Ranged Region %@", _beaconRegion.identifier );
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

And this is the transmitter-Code:

configViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@interface ConfigViewController : UIViewController <CBPeripheralManagerDelegate>

@property (strong,nonatomic) CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSDictionary *beaconPeripheralData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBPeripheralManager *PeripheralManager;

@end
```

ConfigViewController.m

```
#import "ConfigViewController.h"

@interface ConfigViewController ()

@end

@implementation ConfigViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self initBeacon];  
}

- (void) peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {
    if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSLog(@"Powered ON");
        [self.PeripheralManager startAdvertising:self.beaconPeripheralData];
    }
    else if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOff){
        NSLog(@"Powered OFF");
        [self.PeripheralManager stopAdvertising];
    }
}

- (void)initBeacon {
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"A5456D78-C85B-44C6-9F20-8268FD25EF8A"];
    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                major:1
                                                minor:1
                                                identifier:@"Museum"];
}

- (IBAction)transmitBeacon:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.beaconPeripheralData = [self.beaconRegion peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:nil];
    self.PeripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:nil];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine for detecting beacons in the background.  Two suggestions:

1. I suspect the problem when the iPad is transmitting is not with the iPad but that the iPhone cannot receive.  Try cycling power to the iPhone tto clear a [known bug in iOS 7.1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946022/ibeacon-didrangebeacons-stops-getting-called-must-reset-device-for-it-to-work/22949187#22949187)
2. iOS can detect iBeacons much more quickly in the foreground if you set up ranging at the same time you set up monitoring.  Move `[self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];` into `initRegion` and take out `stopRangingBeaconsInRegion` entirely.

Once you have done (2), repeat your tests in the foreground and look for your log statement `Ranged Region`. You should see this every second when the beacon is on.

In the background, know that [it can take up to 15 minutes](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html) to both detect an iBeacon and detect that an iBeacon is no longer around. Again, watch your log lines for hints about the current state, and know that you cannot get a new region entry event until you first get a region exit event or reboot your phone.

Comment: Calling monitoring and ranging at the same time really did help in detecting beacons faster.
I also got three Estimote Beacons now for test-purposes and with those both devices can receive notifications. Therefore I still think the iPad was the trouble. Nevertheless it's working now, so thanks for the tip with the ranging & monitoring.